# Apply parts of the CSS attributs of a class to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now the question is far more complicated then what it seems. I am not looking for how to apply a CSS Class to a DOM element, I already know how to do that (`<div class="MyCssCLass"></div>`)

I am trying to apply **parts** of the CSS attributes of a class to a DOM element.

Lets says I have to following CSS:

```
.MyClass
{
    background-color:red;
    color:blue;
}
```

and this HTML

```
<div id="MyDiv">Some text</div>
```

Now lets say I want to apply only the background-color to `MyDiv` I can't just do:

```
<div id="MyDiv" class="MyClass">Some text</div>
```

Because this will also apply the CSS color attribute to `MyDiv` and this would be bad.

By now you are probably thinking why the hell don't you just override the CSS Class with your own CSS? or why don't you just create another class `MyBckgrdClr` with just `background-color:red;` and give it to `MyDiv`?

Well... lets just say life isn't always that simple.

And with all this wisdom of mine I tried something using JQuery:

Here I am dynamically creating another `<div>` and giving him the `MyClass` CSS class.

```
var MyClassElement = $('<div id="MyClassElement">').addClass('MyClass');
```

Then I will insert it into the `body`

```
$('body').append(MyClassElement);
```

Now I will attempt to change the background of `MyDiv`

```
$("#MyDiv").css("background", MyClassElement.css("background"));
```

Now this work great in Chrome but not so much in Mozilla, IE, Opera...

But HEY! I still have some wisdom left! So lets try something else!

What if I use a Javascript approach?

First thing that comes to mind is this line of code:

```
document.getElementById('MyDiv').style.background = document.getElementById('MyClassElement').style.background;
```

But that didn't worked either... But this time even Chrome did not display the background properly...

So... what the hell should I do now...

...
...

Hum...

...
...
...
...

Oh! Yeah! Got it! I'll use the thing nobody seems to use these day. What is it call again... Oh yeah debugging.

Lets check what `document.getElementById('MyClassElement').style.background` returns

So I inserted:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('MyClassElement').style.background);
```

just after the `$('body').append(MyClassElement);` line and I poped that F12 to see what in that console:

```
(an empty string)
```

...

Now I am beginning to run out of wisdom real fast.

Is there anyone here wiser than me who could tell me what I did wrong and how to achieve this?

What I am looking for is

**Why did the JQuery part work just fine in chrome and not in the other browser? and why did javascript failed for all browsers?**

Fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/7h2Lsxmx/3/

**P.S.** I also noted that any CSS attributes in `.MyClass` don't seems to change any of the `.style` attributes of a Javascript DOM Element neither is `.css()` for the JQuery counterpart.

**EDIT:**

Here is some more explanation.

I have 5 CSS file.

dark.css, light.css, gray.css, blueish.css, kindOfGreen.css

They all have the same class's in them but with different values for each attributes.

So dark.css might be:

```
.MyClass
{
    background-color:black;
    color:gray;
}
```

and Blueish.css might be:

```
.MyClass
{
    background-color:(Put rgb for dark blue here);
    color:blue;
}
```

So to change the color of my page I can just include a different css file on runtime using PHP.
Now you guys should start to see where I am going with this.

1- User choose theme
2- Store choice of theme in cookie
2- Reload page with the appropriate css file

since this is all dynamic I can't (@Matthias I won't) go and hard code a class for each and every properties that change value in each of the five css file if can just make the code work in at least mozilla and IE. Can't change the class because its being used on other elements as well so that would change them which isn't good either.

Comment: "Now I am beginning to run out of wisdom real fast." - Sebastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style` only gives you access to the inline style of an element. To access all the styling properties, use `getComputedStyles`. [More details and examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: wow... just wow... you are the person with the most wisdom I've ever seen my hole life... Is your real name Jesus? Cause you just did a miracle!

Answer (score 1):

```
.red-background { 
  background-color: red;
}

.blue-text-color {
  color: blue;
}

<div class="red-background">This div has a red background</div>

<div class="blue-text-color">This div has blue text color</div>

<div class="red-background blue-text-color">This div has a red background AND blue text color</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is a question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can apply multiple classes to one element? Just separate them using a space. Then you can split your selector.

Otherwise, you can always write a different selector, for example, one that only targets `div`s with the specified class: "div.MyClass".

Using JavaScript for this seems not to be the best way, in my opinion.

Comment: The question seems weird for me too, but OP stated he isn't allowed to change/add css classes.

Comment: Often "isn't allowed to" translates to "doesn't want to" :-)

Comment: Yep I might have made this more complicated then it really is but why is the JQuery part of my code work in chrome and not in the other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as in what case you cannot add more css classes.

Anyway, override the css adding 'important' proprity.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#MyClass").css('color','black','important');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7h2Lsxmx/1/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7h2Lsxmx/3/ this is basicaly the code I have. but it doesn't work in mozilla. and this is the problem